# Design pattern to refactor code with nested if else and switch statements

Tags: java, design-patterns, switch-statement, refactoring, nested-if

I have to refactor a bulky existing code. Gone through a lot of similar questions on SO and other sites, still confused. If anyone can put some light or any idea will be of great help.

There are 5 drop downs and I need to update the view based upon the slected values in drop downs.
First drop down has following options:

```
"TOP DOWN BUDGET"
"TEMPLATE BUDGET"
"ORIGINAL BUDGET"
"REVISED BUDGET"
```

Second drop down has following options:

```
"Day"
"Week"
"Month"
"Quarter"
"Year"
```

Third drop down has following options:

```
"Details"
"Summary"
```

Fourth drop down has following options:

```
"Hours"
"Dollars"
```

Fifth drop down has following options:

```
 "StartDate"
 "EndDate"
```

Now code has following scenario:

```
public List<WorkPlanReport> XYZ(...){//opening of some method XYZ....

List<WorkPlanReport> workPlanReportList=null;
switch(first_Drop_Down_Value){

    case "TOP DOWN BUDGET":
        List<TaskDetails> timeLine=getTimeLine("firstDropDownA", second_drop_down_val, third_drop_down_val, fourth_drop_down_val);
        workPlanReportList=setWorkPlanByTimeLine(timeLine, "firstDropDownA", second_drop_down_val, third_drop_down_val, fourth_drop_down_val);
        break;
    case "TEMPLATE BUDGET":
        List<TaskDetails> timeLine=getTimeLine("firstDropDownB", second_drop_down_val, third_drop_down_val, fourth_drop_down_val, fifth_dd_val);
        workPlanReportList=setWorkPlanByTimeLine(timeLine, "firstDropDownA", second_drop_down_val, third_drop_down_val, fourth_drop_down_val);
        break;
    case "ORIGINAL BUDGET":
        List<TaskDetails> timeLine=getTimeLine("firstDropDownC", second_drop_down_val, third_drop_down_val, fourth_drop_down_val, fifth_dd_val);
        workPlanReportList=setWorkPlanByTimeLine(timeLine, "firstDropDownA", second_drop_down_val, third_drop_down_val, fourth_drop_down_val);
        break;
    case "REVISED BUDGET":
        List<TaskDetails> timeLine=getTimeLine("firstDropDownD", second_drop_down_val, third_drop_down_val, fourth_drop_down_val, fifth_dd_val);
        workPlanReportList=setWorkPlanByTimeLine(timeLine, "firstDropDownA", second_drop_down_val, third_drop_down_val, fourth_drop_down_val);
        break;

}

return workPlanReportList;
}// Closing of some method XYZ....

private List<TaskDetails> getTimeLine(String first_Drop_Down_Value, String second_dd_val, third_dd_val, fourth_dd_val, String fifth_dd_val){

    switch(second_Drop_Down_Value){

    case "Day":
        if(third_dd_val.equals("Details")){
            if(fourth_dd_val.equals("Hours")){
                if(fifth_dd_val.equals("startDate"){
                //prepare query & call DB for fetching days timeline for hours details of TOP DOWN BUDGET filtered by start date...
                }
                else// means endDate{
                //prepare query & call DB for fetching days timeline for hours details of TOP DOWN BUDGET filtered by end date...
                }
            }
            else{//means Dollars
                if(fifth_dd_val.equals("startDate"){
                //prepare query & call DB for fetching days timeline for dollars details of TOP DOWN BUDGET filtered by start date...
                }
                else// means endDate{
                //prepare query & call DB for fetching days timeline for dollars details of TOP DOWN BUDGET filtered by end date...
                }
            }   
        }
        else// means summary...
        {
            if(fourth_dd_val.equals("Hours")){
                if(fifth_dd_val.equals("startDate"){
                //prepare query & call DB for fetching days timeline for 'hours' "summary" of TOP DOWN BUDGET filtered by start date...
                }
                else// means endDate{
                //prepare query & call DB for fetching days timeline for hours summary of TOP DOWN BUDGET filtered by end date...
                }
            }
            else{//means Dollars
                if(fifth_dd_val.equals("startDate"){
                //prepare query & call DB for fetching days timeline for dollars details of TOP DOWN BUDGET filtered by start date...
                }
                else// means endDate{
                //prepare query & call DB for fetching days timeline for dollars details of TOP DOWN BUDGET filtered by end date...
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    case "Week":
            //....similar code as in case "Day" just here we need to fetch data week-wise
            break;
    case "Month":
            //....similar code as in case "Day" just here we need to fetch data month-wise
            break;
    case "Quarter":
            //....similar code as in case "Day" just here we need to fetch data quarter-wise
            break;
    case "Year":
            //....similar code as in case "Day" just here we need to fetch data year-wise
            break;
    }
}


private List<WorkPlanReport> setWorkPlanByTimeLine(List<TaskDetails> timeLine, String "firstDropDownA", String second_drop_down_val, String third_drop_down_val, String fourth_drop_down_val){

WorkPlanReport wpr=new WorkPlanReport();
// Here I have real mess..., Iterating the timeLine list and have switch case and inside switch case multilevel nesting of if else to decide which setter we need to use to set the value.

for example:

If it is "TOP DOWN BUDGET" in first drop-down, "Day" in second drop-down, "Details" in third drop down, "Hours" in fourth drop-down & "StartDate" in fifth drop-down, I have to call follwing code:

wpr.setTDBDetailsHoursByStartDate(taskDetails.getTDBDetailsByHourStartDayView());

If it is "TOP DOWN BUDGET" in first drop-down, "Day" in second drop-down, "Details" in third drop down, "Hours" in fourth drop-down & "EndDate" in fifth drop-down, I have to call follwing code:
wpr.setTDBDetailsHoursByEndDate(taskDetails.getTDBDetailsByHourEndDayView());
```

}

This code is more than 1000 lines, and I am deseparate to refactor it using some suitable design pattern.

WorkPlanReport & TaskDetails DTOs have few similar types of properties in common and many other different properties also.

I am not allowed to alter those DTOs because those are used in some related common code base.

EDIT: This is a method being used in this code. I tried my level best to make it simple but couldn't come up with any working idea.

```
private void setSummaryColumns(String DolOrHr, String columnFilter,
            Map<String, String> filterBy, Object[] obj,
            WorkplanReport workplanReport, TemplateDump td) {
        switch(filterBy.get(columnFilter)){
        case "TOP DOWN":
            td.setTopDownBudgetStartDate(obj[1] != null ? (Date)obj[1]:null);
            td.setTopDownBudgetEndDate(obj[2] != null ? (Date)obj[2]:null);
             workplanReport.setStartDatebyMajorMeasure(obj[1] != null ? obj[1].toString():"-");
             workplanReport.setEndDatebyMajorMeasure(obj[2] != null ? obj[2].toString():"-");
             workplanReport.setDolorHrsbyMajorMeasure(obj[3] != null ? obj[3].toString():"-");
            if(DolOrHr.equals("BudgetDollars"))
                td.setTopDownBudgetDollars(obj[3] != null ? (BigDecimal)obj[3]:null);

            else
                td.setTopDownBudgetHours(obj[3] != null ? (BigDecimal)obj[3]:null);
            break;
        case "TEMPLATE":
            td.setTemplateBudgetStartDate(obj[1] != null ? (Date)obj[1]:null);
            td.setTemplateBudgetEndDate(obj[2] != null ? (Date)obj[2]:null);
            workplanReport.setStartDatebyTemplateBudget(obj[1] != null ? obj[1].toString():"-");
            workplanReport.setEndDatebyTemplateBudget(obj[2] != null ? obj[2].toString():"-");
            workplanReport.setDolorHrsbyTemplateBudget(obj[3] != null ? obj[3].toString():"-");
            if(DolOrHr.equals("BudgetDollars"))
                td.setTemplateBudgetDollars(obj[3] != null ? (BigDecimal)obj[3]:null);
            else
                td.setTemplateBudgetHours(obj[3] != null ? (BigDecimal)obj[3]:null);
            break;
        case "ORIGINAL":
            td.setOriginalBudgetStartDate(obj[1] != null ? (Date)obj[1]:null);
            td.setOriginalBudgetEndDate(obj[2] != null ? (Date)obj[2]:null);
            workplanReport.setOrgStartDate(obj[1] != null ? obj[1].toString():"-");
            workplanReport.setOrgEndDate(obj[2] != null ? obj[2].toString():"-");
            workplanReport.setOrgBudgetedDollarsHours(obj[3] != null ? obj[3].toString():"-");
            if(DolOrHr.equals("BudgetDollars"))
                td.setOriginalBudgetDollars(obj[3] != null ? (BigDecimal)obj[3]:null);
            else
                td.setOriginalBudgetHours(obj[3] != null ? (BigDecimal)obj[3]:null);
            break;
        case "REVISED":
            td.setRevisedBudgetStartDate(obj[1] != null ? (Date)obj[1]:null);
            td.setRevisedBudgetEndDate(obj[2] != null ? (Date)obj[2]:null);
            workplanReport.setRevStartDate(obj[1] != null ? obj[1].toString():"-");
            workplanReport.setRevEndDate(obj[2] != null ? obj[2].toString():"-");
            workplanReport.setRevBudgetedDollarsHours(obj[3] != null ? obj[3].toString():"-");
            if(DolOrHr.equals("BudgetDollars"))
                td.setRevisedBudgetDollars(obj[3] != null ? (BigDecimal)obj[3]:null);
            else
                td.setRevisedBudgetHours(obj[3] != null ? (BigDecimal)obj[3]:null);
            break;

        case "MANAGER":

            td.setManagerBudgetStartDate(obj[1] != null ? (Date)obj[1]:null);
            td.setManagerBudgetEndDate(obj[2] != null ? (Date)obj[2]:null);
            workplanReport.setStartDatebyManagersRevised(obj[1] != null ? obj[1].toString():"-");
            workplanReport.setEndDatebyManagersRevised(obj[2] != null ? obj[2].toString():"-");
            workplanReport.setDolorHrsbyManagersRevised(obj[3] != null ? obj[3].toString():"-");
            if(DolOrHr.equals("BudgetDollars"))
                td.setManagerBudgetDollars(obj[3] != null ? (BigDecimal)obj[3]:null);
            else
                td.setManagerBudgetHours(obj[3] != null ? (BigDecimal)obj[3]:null);
            break;
        case "ACTUAL":
            td.setActualBudgetStartDate(obj[1] != null ? (Date)obj[1]:null);
            td.setActualBudgetEndDate(obj[2] != null ? (Date)obj[2]:null);
            workplanReport.setStartDatebyActual(obj[1] != null ? obj[1].toString():"-");
            workplanReport.setEndDatebyActual(obj[2] != null ? obj[2].toString():"-");
            workplanReport.setDolorHrsbyActual(obj[3] != null ? obj[3].toString():"-");
            if(DolOrHr.equals("BudgetDollars"))
                td.setActualBudgetDollars(obj[3] != null ? (BigDecimal)obj[3]:null);
            else
                td.setActualBudgetHours(obj[3] != null ? (BigDecimal)obj[3]:null);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: it's a terrible piece of code, give me an hour to digest it :)

Comment: Forget my Idea, you would end up with ~160 single Strategy classes. Way to much.

Comment: So, is this an SQL query-builder of some sort? At least the "prepare query & call" part should be refactored out and have the method just return a corresponding query.

Comment: Is there duplication in the queries as well, i.e. how are Day/Week/Month etc.queries different from each other and how Details/Summary and Hours/Dollars affect the queries that are executed? Do the different budget types target different DB tables or procedures?

Comment: @Mick: Data is stored date wise. For week, month, quarter & year view we are using aggregate functions to sum and display.
Details query has 3-4 additional columns selecting from DB compared to summary. Different budget type are the different columns in same table. It is 8-10 years old code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You duplicate many things in the actual code.
Before thinking about patterns you could use, I advise you to start removing the actual **real issue** : the code duplication that is an anti pattern.

The minor dup is the first level `switch` statement :

```
case "TOP DOWN BUDGET":
    List<TaskDetails> timeLine=getTimeLine("firstDropDownA", second_drop_down_val, third_drop_down_val, fourth_drop_down_val);
    workPlanReportList=setWorkPlanByTimeLine(timeLine, "firstDropDownA", second_drop_down_val, third_drop_down_val, fourth_drop_down_val);
    break;
case "TEMPLATE BUDGET":
    List<TaskDetails> timeLine=getTimeLine("firstDropDownB", second_drop_down_val, third_drop_down_val, fourth_drop_down_val, fifth_dd_val);
    workPlanReportList=setWorkPlanByTimeLine(timeLine, "firstDropDownA", second_drop_down_val, third_drop_down_val, fourth_drop_down_val);
    break;
 ...
```

Almost all is duplicated. 
The single variant thing is the first parameter passed to `getTimeLine()`.
Replace the String that you use in the `switch` statement  by a `Budget` enum and this part could be also short as :

```
Budget budget = Budget.valueOf(first_Drop_Down_Value);

List<TaskDetails> timeLine=getTimeLine(budget.getValueForTimeLine(), second_drop_down_val, third_drop_down_val, fourth_drop_down_val);
workPlanReportList=setWorkPlanByTimeLine(timeLine, "firstDropDownA", second_drop_down_val, third_drop_down_val, fourth_drop_down_val);
```

And seemingly the big duplication is located in `getTimeLine()`.
You could apply exactly the same recipe for each thing that you duplicate and where the single real differences are parameters that you could pass.
So instead of switching on the possibilities of the second dropdown ("Day"
"Week","Month","Quarter","Year") introduce an enum to convey this information:

```
TimePeriod timePeriod = TimePeriod.valueOf(second_Drop_Down_Value);
```

Do the same thing for the third dropdown ("Details" and "Summary") :

```
DetailLevel detailLevel = DetailLevel.valueOf(third_Drop_Down_Value);
```

And then give a way to change the granularity of the fetch according to the `TimePeriod` and the `DetailLevel` selected. It will just be two parameters passed in the method that retrieve the data.

By stopping here your refactoring task the `getTimeLine()` looks like really shorter and simpler :

```
private List<TaskDetails> getTimeLine(String first_Drop_Down_Value, String second_dd_val, third_dd_val, fourth_dd_val, String fifth_dd_val){

    TimePeriod timePeriod = TimePeriod.valueOf(second_Drop_Down_Value);
    DetailLevel detailLevel = DetailLevel.valueOf(third_Drop_Down_Value);

    if(fourth_dd_val.equals("Hours")){
        if(fifth_dd_val.equals("startDate"){           
          fetch(...,....,timePeriod, detailLevel) // <- pass the enums
        }
        else// means endDate{
        //prepare query & call DB for fetching days timeline for hours details of TOP DOWN BUDGET filtered by end date...
          fetch(...,....,timePeriod, detailLevel) // <- pass the enums
        }
    }
    else{//means Dollars
        if(fifth_dd_val.equals("startDate"){
        //prepare query & call DB for fetching days timeline for dollars details of TOP DOWN BUDGET filtered by start date...
          fetch(...,....,timePeriod, detailLevel) // <- pass the enums
        }
        else// means endDate{
        //prepare query & call DB for fetching days timeline for dollars details of TOP DOWN BUDGET filtered by end date...
          fetch(...,....,timePeriod, detailLevel) // <- pass the enums
        }
    }   
}
```

---

**Edit**

About the part where you invoke distinct setters in the cases of the `switch` statement, you still have many similarities that you can factor out.
Take by example the cases : "TOP DOWN" and "ORIGINAL"  :

```
td.setTopDownBudgetStartDate(obj[1] != null ? (Date)obj[1]:null);
td.setTopDownBudgetEndDate(obj[2] != null ? (Date)obj[2]:null);
```

versus

```
td.setOriginalBudgetStartDate(obj[1] != null ? (Date)obj[1]:null);
td.setOriginalBudgetEndDate(obj[2] != null ? (Date)obj[2]:null);
```

Then :

```
workplanReport.setStartDatebyMajorMeasure(obj[1] != null ? obj[1].toString():"-");
workplanReport.setEndDatebyMajorMeasure(obj[2] != null ? obj[2].toString():"-");
workplanReport.setDolorHrsbyMajorMeasure(obj[3] != null ? obj[3].toString():"-");
```

versus :

```
workplanReport.setOrgStartDate(obj[1] != null ? obj[1].toString():"-");
workplanReport.setOrgEndDate(obj[2] != null ? obj[2].toString():"-");
workplanReport.setOrgBudgetedDollarsHours(obj[3] != null ? obj[3].toString():"-");
```

And so for...

Finally, the same logic is applied but the computations are not assigned to the same setters in `WorkPlanReport` and `TemplateDump`  objects .
`WorkPlanReport` and `TemplateDump` appear as classes with a lot of individual fields that could and even should be extracted into specific classes because these are related between them : it is the principle of high cohesion.

For example for the "TOP DOWN" dump , you could define :

```
public class TopDownTemplateDump {
    private Date budgetStartDate;
    private Date budgetEndDate;
    private BigDecimal budgetDollars;
    private BigDecimal budgetHours;
    // and so for ...
    // setters - getters 
}
```

For the "ORIGINAL" dump , you could define :

```
public class OriginalTemplateDump {
    private Date budgetStartDate;
    private Date budgetEndDate;
    private BigDecimal budgetDollars;
    private BigDecimal budgetHours;
    // and so for ...
    // setters - getters
}
```

And the `TemplateDump` that holds each "dump part" could look like now :

```
public class TemplateDump {
   private TopDownTemplateDump topDownTemplateDump;
   private OriginalTemplateDump originalTemplateDump;
   ...
}
```

But does it make sense to duplicate all these "Dump" classes while they will own exactly the same structure ? Not really.
You should probably extract them into a base class :

```
public abstract class AbstractTemplateDump {
    private Date budgetStartDate;
    private Date budgetEndDate;
    private BigDecimal budgetDollars;
    private BigDecimal budgetHours;
    // and so for ...
    // setters - getters
}
```

Concrete parts can now inherit from `AbstractTemplateDump` such as :

```
public class TopDownTemplateDump extends AbstractTemplateDump{
    // add subclass specifities here
}
```

Now you have an uniform way to set the data of the `TemplateDump` instance. So the `switch` is not required any longer.
Follow exactly the same logic for `WorkPlanReport`.

Your code could look like now :

```
AbstractTemplateDump absTd = td.getDumpPart(filterBy.get(columnFilter));
AbstractReportPart absRp = workplanReport.getReportPart(filterBy.get(columnFilter));

absTd.setBudgetStartDate(obj[1] != null ? (Date)obj[1]:null);
absTd.setBudgetEndDate(obj[2] != null ? (Date)obj[2]:null);
absRp.setStartDateby(obj[1] != null ? obj[1].toString():"-");
absRp.setEndDateby(obj[2] != null ? obj[2].toString():"-");
absRp.setDolorHrsby(obj[3] != null ? obj[3].toString():"-");
// ...
```

Comment: This time I can say: Great answer! I just looked at the question and was baffled. Wanted to answer, but couldn't come up with a plausible solution

Comment: @Lino Thank you very much. The question exposes indeed many things and issues. Handling it in its wholeness is complicated enough. So I didn't handle each point but I just focused on the part where I think that we could apply some easy but valuable improvements.

Comment: I thought about using the mentioned *Strategy Pattern* from the comments and combining it with the *Builder Pattern* to create some form of fluent interface, that decides what should be done, but that would probably be overkill :)

Comment: @davidxxx: +1 for the patience and efforts to provide a real useful answer. My main concern is "Is there any design pattern or approach which avoids manual code call to specific setter methods based upon conditions?"

Comment: Just to be more clear, I edited my question & kept a method being used in this code. IF any one can have a look to suggest something to reduce the redundancy of code.

Comment: @Shailesh Saxena You are welcome. Inheritancy and introducing a base class seem really enough here as you want "only" set data. I updated to handle this second part.